# Get all image sizes from flickr JSON rss feed

Tags: php, json, image, feed, flickr

With php, I'm loading this flickr json feed (is an example) and storing it.

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=39027292@N00&lang=es-es&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

The item feed got this structure:

```
{
    "title": "bridge3",
    "link": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/barbbowman\/14098165124\/",
    "media": {"m":"http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2933\/14098165124_ea43f1f6eb_m.jpg"},
    "date_taken": "2013-09-05T15:31:36-08:00",
    "description": " <p><a href=\"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/people\/barbbowman\/\">geek.lady<\/a> public\u00f3 una foto:<\/p> <p><a href=\"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/barbbowman\/14098165124\/\" title=\"bridge3\"><img src=\"http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2933\/14098165124_ea43f1f6eb_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"bridge3\" \/><\/a><\/p> ",
    "published": "2014-05-03T17:49:46Z",
    "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"geek.lady\")",
    "author_id": "39027292@N00",
    "tags": ""
   },
```

The problem is (i've tried with a lot of feed examples), all the 
media:

```
"media": {"m":"http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2933\/14098165124_ea43f1f6eb_m.jpg"},
```

It's only the medium size, and i want all the available sizes shown in there. 
Is it possible? maybe changing the feed adress parameters?

Comment: All available sizes? Can you be bit more specific? You mean all available sizes of a single image or just the size of image in each JSON row?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it via api but here's the logic for image link.

For small image you juste need to replace "_m" by "_s" in your link before your extension like that

**Medium :**

http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2933/14098165124_ea43f1f6eb_m.jpg

**Small :**

http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2933/14098165124_ea43f1f6eb_s.jpg

For **normal**  juste remove "_m" or "_s"

**Example :**

http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2933/14098165124_ea43f1f6eb.jpg

You have other size with : "_z", "_q" etc.

See the docs and look into **Arguments --> Extras** :

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.galleries.getPhotos.html